# Schlafli symbols for antiprisms, crossed antiprisms

Tags: geometry, notation, definition, polygons, polyhedra

I am familiar with Schlafli symbols for polygons and polygrams, but it gets way more complicated for antiprisms.  I get that {7} describes a heptagon, {7/2} describes a heptagram with 7 edges where each edge skips to every 2nd vertex around the shape, and {7/3} describes a heptagram with 7 edges where each edge skips to every 3rd vertex around the shape.

However, looking at an antiprism, [image: hexagonalantiprism], the Schlafli symbol is either s{2,2n} or sr{2,n}.  Does anyone know how to interpret this?

Finally, does anyone know how to notate with a Schlafli symbol how many vertices are skipped from the top base to the bottom base (or vice versa) in the following crossed antiprisms?  Also, does anyone have a good definition for a crossed antiprism?  Any help on any part of this is appreciated.[image: heptagrammalantiprism1] [image: heptagrammalantiprism2]

Comment: In this context, it helps to make a distinction between $\{7/3\}$ and $\{7/4\}$. (I think of the latter as being inside-out, in some sense, even though a star polygon doesn't really have an inside. This notion can be formalized using normal vectors.) A [crossed antiprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiprism#Star_antiprism) is just an antiprism of a polygon $\{p/q\}$ where $q>\tfrac12p$.

Comment: I would hesitate to call an antiprism a snub. As an abstract polyhedron, $sr\{2,n\}$ would have some [digon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digon) faces and only rotation symmetry, while an antiprism has no digons and has reflection symmetry. And some level of abstraction is necessary, if we're talking about star polygons or $\{2,n\}$. Considering that $\{2,n\}$ is made of only digons, I think we'd need to add something to the Schlafli symbol $sr\{2,n\}$ to explicitly remove the digons in the end.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at [these](https://youtu.be/8TSDZlJuTfc) [videos](https://youtu.be/zVqwaEffkTg) (time 7:32-7:54 and 1:36-2:30 respectively) to see how snubs can be constructed in general.

Comment: For your first question: Do you know what $\{2,n\}$ means by itself? (There are several possibilities.)

Comment: For your last question: Continuing from my first comment, an antiprism of a polygon $\{p/q\}$ has vertex coordinates as given on Wikipedia, with $n=p/q$: $$v_k=(\cos(k\pi q/p),\sin(k\pi q/p),(-1)^kh),$$ $$0\leq k<2p,$$ and it has triangular faces connecting vertices $v_k,v_{k+1},v_{k+2}$ (modulo $2p$), and a polygonal $\{p/q\}$ face connecting the even vertices $v_{2k}$, and another connecting the odd vertices $v_{2k+1}$. You can equate a triangle's two edge lengths, and solve to find the antiprism's half-height $h$. -- Is that sufficient as a definition?

Comment: I don't really know what {2,n} means, that's one of the things I was asking about.  I was ideally looking for a solution explained more as a concept (as in "7/2 means that the shape has seven edges and each edge skips to every 2nd vertex") rather than a formula for determining the number or location of vertices or faces.

Comment: Okay, how about this: A $\{p/q\}$ antiprism is two congruent $\{p/q\}$ polygons, sharing their axis of symmetry, connected by equilateral triangles.... Given one of the two polygons, there are only two possible ways to place a triangle, sharing one edge with the polygon, such that the triangle's opposite vertex could be a vertex of the second polygon. Specifically, the triangle could slope away from the axis, or it could go through the axis. The latter case has $q>\tfrac12p$, and is crossed.

Comment: (The triangle can rotate around the first polygon's edge, so that its opposite vertex traces a circle. The symmetry and congruence of the two polygons imply that all vertices must be on a cylinder. The circle intersects the cylinder in two points, so there are two ways to place the triangle.)

Comment: (Actually, the circle intersects the cylinder in four points, but two are above and two are below the first polygon. The four resulting antiprisms are congruent in pairs.)

Comment: Thanks for those.  If you put one as an answer rather than a comment I can award you the bounty.

Comment: To compare my answer with relatives of the cube, see the picture on the right here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid#Construction_of_Archimedean_solids

Answer (score 2):

I think your questions should have been split into two posts: one about Schlafli symbols for convex antiprisms, and one about crossed antiprisms. The latter has been answered in comments, so here I'll answer the former. (I hope you're familiar with Schlafli symbols for relatives of the cube $\{4,3\}$, for comparison.)

$\{2\}$ is a *digon*, a polygon with two edges. $\{n,2\}$ is a *dihedron*, a polyhedron with two $n$-gon faces. $\{2,n\}$ is a *hosohedron*, a polyhedron with $n$ digon faces. These can be thought of either as [abstract polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope), or as polyhedra with curved faces, or as degenerate polyhedra with coincident faces.

[image: Dihedron]

(Each polyhedron is shown from a top view and a side view.)

The operations of truncation and rectification can be applied to these:

[image: Dihedron modifications]

And then the cantellate $rr\{2,n\}$ can be twisted to make the snub:

[image: Dihedron snub]

As you can see, this is not quite an antiprism; it has some digon faces, and no reflection symmetry.

As a different way to construct the snub, the omnitruncate $tr\{2,n\}$ can be alternated (meaning every other vertex is deleted, so e.g. a decagon becomes a pentagon). But what is alternation exactly, when digons are allowed? Does a square become an edge, or a digon? It is ambiguous.

Well, if the digons are removed in the end, everything seems to work fine.